How to clear WooCommerce products zero sale price?
I am creating a WooCommerce shop with 4000 products. The product list is updated daily by the manufacturer, which is then updated via FTP in this webshop.
Unfortunately, the manufacturer gives a value of "0" as the sale price for non-discounted products. How can I delete this value?
I tried using the following code:
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 10, 2 );
function custom_price_html( $price, $product ) {

    if ( $product->is_on_sale() && $product->get_sale_price() == '0' ) {
        $price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) ) ) . $product->get_price_suffix();
    }
    return $price;
}

But only the displayed price get changed (the webshop shows the original price), but if I add it in the cart, it is taken into account with the price "0".
I want not only the original price to be displayed for the "0" sale price, I want to delete it.
By the way, the price filter doesn't work that way on the website either, because it considers it a "0" price.

There are missing things in your code… You should try to use the following instead, that will filter zero sale prices, resetting them:
// Adjust product active price
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'adjust_product_active_price', 20, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'adjust_product_active_price', 20, 2);
function adjust_product_active_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( $price == 0 && $product->get_regular_price() > 0 ) {
        return floatval($product->get_regular_price());
    }
    return $price;
}

// Empty product sale price with zero value
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'adjust_product_zero_sale_price', 20, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price', 'adjust_product_zero_sale_price', 20, 2 );
function adjust_product_zero_sale_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( $price == 0 ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $price;
}

// Utility function (Remove zero sale prices)
function remove_zero_prices( $prices ) {
    foreach( $prices as $key => $price ) {
        if ( $price == 0 ) {
            unset($prices[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $prices;
}

// Adjust displayed variable price
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'adjust_variable_price_html', 20, 2 );
function adjust_variable_price_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

    if ( min($prices['sale_price']) > 0 ) {
        return $price_html;
    }
    $active_prices  = remove_zero_prices($prices['price']);
    $regular_prices = $prices['regular_price'];
    $min_price      = min(array_merge($active_prices, $regular_prices));
    $max_price      = max(array_merge($active_prices, $regular_prices));
    $min_reg_price  = current($regular_prices);
    $max_reg_price  = end($regular_prices);

    if ( $product->is_on_sale() && $min_reg_price === $max_reg_price ) {
        $price_html = wc_format_sale_price( wc_price( $max_reg_price ), wc_price( $min_price ) );
    } elseif ( $min_price !== $max_price ) {
        $price_html = wc_format_price_range( $min_price, $max_price );
    } else {
        $price_html = wc_price( $min_price );
    }
    return $price_html;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_is_on_sale', 'filter_variable_product_is_on_sale', 20, 2);
function filter_variable_product_is_on_sale( $is_on_sale, $product ) {
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $is_on_sale = false;
        
        foreach( $product->get_available_variations('') as $variation ) {
            if( $variation->is_on_sale() ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return $is_on_sale;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.
Related:

Temporary global sale price discount for all products in WooCommerce
Change product prices via a hook in WooCommerce 3+


Hello LoicTheAztec! I tested the code in several ways.
There are 2 more problems.
1, Sorting by price doesn't work (I think it's because it takes a zero value into account)
2. If the sale price of a product has a value greater than zero, the product will not appear on the products archive page
Can you help me with this? Thanks!

My answer heere is just answering your initial question… Sorting prices for example is another problem that should be asked in a new question...

I have another code on the site because the manufacturer marks the "out of stock" product as zero regular price.
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'themelocation_product_query' );
function themelocation_product_query( $q ){
$meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
$meta_query[] = array(
'key' => '_price',
'value' => 0,
'compare' => '='
);
$q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
Your code and this together cause problem #2 (I turn off, yours is perfect).Could you change your code so that zero price products don't show up? Instead of the above code with something else?

So the solution should be better to update all zero sale prices in the database. So is better to ask a new question tagged "woocommerce" and linked to this thread, adding in it my answer code and your comment code, explaining things. Once done notify me here.

Hello LoicTheAztec! I added a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78503742/25064274

Did you try to add an empty string to the sale price?
function clear_zero_sale_price( $product ) {
    if ( $product->get_sale_price() == '0' ) {
        $product->set_sale_price( '' );
        $product->save();
    }
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_product_set_stock', 'clear_zero_sale_price' );

