How to clear WooCommerce products sale price with zero value from database?
I am creating a WooCommerce shop. I update my products daily, using Product Import Export For WooCommerce plugin, from a CSV file (via manufacturer's FTP). If a product is not on sale, the table contains a zero value. If a product is "out of stock", the regular price is zero.
I would like the zero sale price to be deleted, and I would also like the zero regular price products not to appear on my page.
I tried to use another code to remove the zero regular price products, but the two codes together do not work correctly.
I need something more as with the current code that I use, the zero sale price remains in the database and the "sort by price" function does not work.
Example:
Product "A": regular price: 1000, sale price: 0
Product "B": regular price: 1000, sale price: 900
Product "C" (out of stock): regular price:0
I would like product "A" to appear with a price of 1,000, product "B" with a price of 900, and product "C" not to appear.
At the same time, "sort by price" should work and there is a price filter on the page, it correctly shows the price range 900-1000 (or 0-1000, it doesn't matter).
This is related to my previous question: How to clear WooCommerce products zero sale price?
#1 Code, that hide zero regular price product:
// Adjust product active price
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'adjust_product_active_price', 20, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'adjust_product_active_price', 20, 2);
function adjust_product_active_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( $price == 0 && $product->get_regular_price() > 0 ) {
        return floatval($product->get_regular_price());
    }
    return $price;
}

// Empty product sale price with zero value
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'adjust_product_zero_sale_price', 20, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price', 'adjust_product_zero_sale_price',     20, 2 );
function adjust_product_zero_sale_price( $price, $product ) {
    if ( $price == 0 ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $price;
}

// Utility function (Remove zero sale prices)
function remove_zero_prices( $prices ) {
    foreach( $prices as $key => $price ) {
        if ( $price == 0 ) {
            unset($prices[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $prices;
}

// Adjust displayed variable price
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'adjust_variable_price_html', 20, 2 );
function adjust_variable_price_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

    if ( min($prices['sale_price']) > 0 ) {
        return $price_html;
    }
    $active_prices  = remove_zero_prices($prices['price']);
    $regular_prices = $prices['regular_price'];
    $min_price      = min(array_merge($active_prices, $regular_prices));
    $max_price      = max(array_merge($active_prices, $regular_prices));
    $min_reg_price  = current($regular_prices);
    $max_reg_price  = end($regular_prices);

    if ( $product->is_on_sale() && $min_reg_price === $max_reg_price ) {
        $price_html = wc_format_sale_price( wc_price( $max_reg_price ), wc_price( $min_price )     );
    } elseif ( $min_price !== $max_price ) {
        $price_html = wc_format_price_range( $min_price, $max_price );
    } else {
        $price_html = wc_price( $min_price );
    }
    return $price_html;
}

   add_filter('woocommerce_product_is_on_sale', 'filter_variable_product_is_on_sale', 20, 2);
   function filter_variable_product_is_on_sale( $is_on_sale, $product ) {
       if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
           $is_on_sale = false;
           
           foreach( $product->get_available_variations('') as $variation ) {
               if( $variation->is_on_sale() ) {
                   return true;
               }
           }
       }
       return $is_on_sale;
   }

#2 Code, that hide zero regular price product
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'themelocation_product_query' );
function themelocation_product_query( $q ){
    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
        $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key'       => '_price',
                    'value'     => 0,
                    'compare'   => '='
                );
    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}


Which tool/plugin are you using to import/update products via that CSV?

WebToffee - Product Import Export    https://www.webtoffee.com/product/product-import-export-woocommerce/

I think that there is certainly a way to filter the data from the CSV when importing/updating via this plugin. You should ask first in the plugin support threads.

On the documentation related to the plugin you are using, I found this related code snippet that could help to change those product zero prices. As commented before, don't hesitate to ask the plugin support...
